# How do I make submit buttons 'print' things in html and make a text input with 100% width in the same line as a <span>, <p>, or <div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

These are my files:

```css
.dir {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.cmdline {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
.cmdline:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.blink_text {
  -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: blinker;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: blinker;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: white;
}
@-moz-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--<>-->
<!--<ink rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css">-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--</>-->

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <span class="dir">~/Link/Hydrogen/Helium/Lithium></span>
  <input class="cmdline" autofocus>
  <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</body>
```

Ignore the comments...
So how do I make it so that when a command is entered, something will be printed? Similar to [telehack.com](http://telehack.com) ? I'm I am also having a problem where I can't seem to make an input with 100% width in the same line as a `span`, `p`, or `div`. Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Ignore the comments"* - If they're not relevant, please [edit] your question to remove them.

Comment: If you have two problems create two separate questions for them.

Comment: Regarding your first question, are you asking us to implement (or explain how to implement) from scratch some JavaScript that will accept user input and print "something"? That seems a fairly broad requirement. Regarding your CSS 100% width problem, how could the input have 100% width if it is "in the same line as a span" that is already taking up space? Do you mean span width + input width should total 100% of the page width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Second Question**

To put the input field beside the directory I wrapped them both in a `<table>`:

**CSS**

```
.intable {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="output" class="dir"></span>
<form id="inform" autocomplete="off">
  <table class="intable">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="dir" id="directory">~/Link/Hydrogen/Helium/Lithium></span>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 100%">
        <input class="cmdline" id="inbox" autofocus>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</form>
```

(I'll explain the `<form>` soon)

**Your First Question**

**Getting Input**

The reason that I put it all in a form was so that retreiving input would be easy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inform").submit(function(e) { //Listen for the user to enter text
    e.preventDefault();             //Keep page from reloading
    var input = $("#inbox").val();  //get entered text
    $("#inbox").val("");            //I assume you want to blank this out afterwards
    printSomething(input);          //Process input and print to page
  });
});
```

**Printing Output**

I added the `<span id="output" class="dir"></span>` so there would be a place to write the output.

```
function printSomething(input)
{
  //Put the directory text + user's input at head of output
  var output = $("#directory").html() + input + "<br />";

  //Replace this bit with your own processing
  if(input.length > 0)
  {
    output += "You entered: " + input;
  } else {
    output += "You didn't enter anything!"
  }
  //So that directory will be on newline, because span does not automatically do that
  output += "<br />";

  //ADD the new content to the output
  $("#output").append(output);
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Keep page from reloading
    var input = $("#inbox").val(); //get entered text
    $("#inbox").val(""); //I assume you want to blank this out afterwards
    printSomething(input);
  });
});

function printSomething(input) //You were a little vague...
  {
    var output = $("#directory").html() + input + "<br />";

    //Replace this bit with your own processing
    if (input.length > 0) {
      output += "You entered: " + input;
    } else {
      output += "You didn't enter anything!"
    }
    output += "<br />";

    $("#output").append(output);
  }
```

```css
.dir {
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.cmdline {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 100%;
}
.cmdline:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.blink_text {
  -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: blinker;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: blinker;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: white;
}
.intable {
  width: 100%;
}
@-moz-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body style="background-color:black;">
  <span id="output" class="dir"></span>
  <form id="inform" autocomplete="off">
    <table class="intable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class="dir" id="directory">~/Link/Hydrogen/Helium/Lithium></span>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100%">
          <input class="cmdline" id="inbox" autofocus>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" />
  </form>
</body>
```